# xrdp only showing blue-green background screen after login

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, raspberry-pi, home-networking, xrdp

I have an RPi 4 on which I installed **xrdp** to connect to it via **MS Remote Desktop**. But after login with the pi's username and the password, the grey login window disappeares and leaves me with the **blue-greenish background**.

#### Before login:

[image: Login screen with blue-greenish background and grey login window with xrdp logo, saying "Just connecting"]

#### After login:

[image: Post-login screen. Just blue-greenish background, grey login window has disappeared.]

There is **no error message** which might indicate what is wrong.

What can I do to fix this? Reinstalling xrdp didn't work. Still the same issue.

*(If noone knows how to fix it: Is there an alternative to xrdp I can use, which works with MS remote desktop?)*

Edit: I am using a **Win 11** PC to connect and the RPi is running the latest **x64 Raspbian "Bullseye"**

Answer (score 2):

Check this out

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70146297/raspberry-pi-remote-desktop-connection-problem-giving-up

Seems like you need a second user. Haven't tried myself yet

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1124829)

Comment: And it's no longer there :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reboot the server. Yes everyone hates destroying uptimes and jumping to the last resort too early. But during the issue I just troubleshooted I saw this screen too and I got a bit further after a reboot. My issue with the session being closed right after the connection attempt was related to someone else having auto login configured in GDM, which is not very safe and unnecessary too.